# Unable to set windbg for windows VM

Tags: windows, windbg

```
I want to debug the kernel of windows server 2019. My physical host is windows 10. My
VM is windows server 2019(VirtualBox). I followed this video on youtube to complete my 
setup<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V7DJ_ptkOpM>.
I got this on my VM which I think it's not the reason I failed
```

```
c:\KDNET>.\kdnet.exe 172.26.48.1 51111
Enabling network debugging on Intel(R) PRO/1000 MT Desktop Adapter.
Manage-bde.exe not present.  Bitlocker presumed disabled.

To debug this machine, run the following command on your debugger host machine.
windbg -k net:port=51111,key=1gofrzddjdu9q.2stxhh3p9pieh.114a4fe4c4vr4.16nbo0k9ghw3v

Then reboot this machine by running shutdown -r -t 0 from this command prompt.
```

```
I run the command
```

> windbg -k net:port=51111,key=1gofrzddjdu9q.2stxhh3p9pieh.114a4fe4c4vr4.16nbo0k9ghw3v

```
The result is this
```

```
Using NET for debugging
Open WinSOCKET 2.0
Failed to initialize IPv6 socket. Error On-2147467259
Will attempt to connect to IPv4 only
Failed to initialize IPv4 socket. Error On-2147467259
Kernel debugger failed initialization. HRESULT  0x80004005
unspecified error
```

Comment: Did you reboot the target as the debugger suggested?

Answer (score 0):

it is trying to connect with IPV6 address, so please use the following command Windbg -k net:port=,key=<key_output_from_kdnet>,target=0.0.0.0

This will try to open the socket connection with IPV4